# Find hex string is utf-8 or utf-16

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ .

I have hex string from file.
Example - 657374696E65 which if utf-8 code will convert to "estine".

Sometime i get  utf-16 code to string.
I need to find, is string in encoded in utf-8 or utf-16 by programatically.

```
std::string input = "657374696E65";

std::string extract = input.substr(0, 4);

unsigned int x;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::hex << extract;
ss >> x;
```

i initially take each 4 substr then convert to ascii then to widestring.

Sometime t get utf-8 too.

Can any one help me to find is the string i have to convert each 2 char or 4 char to ascii.

Comment: Where are you getting strings from such that you don't even know what they contain?

Comment: You can check size of null at the end of string.

Comment: This Text i read from pdf content stream.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do before further processing is undoing the hex encoding, by putting raw bytes into an `std::string` or `std::vector<unsigned char>`. Then you can post-process your collection of bytes by UTF-8 or UTF-16 decoding into the string type your application needs.

There is no safe way to detect whether a string is UTF-8 or UTF-16. Microsoft tried to do so in a quite clever way in their [IsTextUnicode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-istextunicode) function. The result was the misinterpretation of files containing the string ["bush hid the facts"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts) (without newline) in Notepad (e.g. on Windows XP).

- If you can ensure that all UTF-16 strings you receive start with a byte order mark (BOM), use the BOM as indicator for UTF-16.
- If you are sure that you strings always contain (amongst other characters) US-ASCII characters, take the appearance of NUL bytes (`'\x00'`) as indicator for UTF-16.
- This is one of the better heuristics Windows used: If there is the patter `\x0D\x0A` (CR/LF), detect the string as UTF-8. This prevents the "bush hid the facts" issue if there is a line break in the string.

Comment: UTF-8 is very easy to parse manually. UTF-16 is a little harder due to endian. If UTF-8 and UTF-16 are your only choices, then simply decode the hex string into bytes, parse a handful of bytes as UTF-8 and if the parse fails than assume UTF-16.